# Error message from dialogflow while configuring knowledge base from URL

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

While creating knowledge base in dialog flow from URL, I am getting message "Error". However I am able to see FAQ which are on this URL when opening in browser. For reference please find below screenshot below, If feasible suggest how can I find exact reason for this error as dialog flow don't give  any other relevant error for this.

URL which I am configuring knowledge base is :
https://www.owens.edu/faq/early-alert/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUhTc.png)

Comment: Open your browser's debugger. The console outputs usually provide more insight into the specific error; you can also check your Network capture in the debugger to see which API call(s) failed.

Answer (score 1):

The full error message is the following:

"Failed to crawl https://www.owens.edu/faq/early-alert. Please verify that your URL is publicly accessible and is hosted on a site that can be indexed by Google Search."

[image]

I have tested the FAQ page you shared and by using the "[Developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)" of Chrome, I was able to see that error message. I suggest you to take a look at the "[Supported content](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/knowledge-bases#supported-content)" documentation for knowledge bases in Dialogflow. In there, you can see the following statement:

- Files from public URLs must have been crawled by the Google search indexer, so that they exist in the search index. You can check this with the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console). Note that the indexer does not keep your content fresh. You must explicitly update your knowledge document when the source content changes.

Therefore, make sure to meet all the requirements listed there.